# Will you be punished if you not stay until sunrise after fajr

Tags: sunni, time, fajr

My uncle told me that if you dont wait until sunrise after fajr prayer you will be punished is this true?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I recommend you to take our [tour] and check our [help]. This post needs some elaboration: stay where and what for? (see [ask]).

Comment: If the answers below satisfy your query please mark the relevant one as accepted. Else please elaborate on your doubts/questions.

Answer (score 2):

**Extracted from this [link](https://islamqa.info/en/100009):**

It is [mustahabb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustahabb) to stay in the mosque after Fajr prayer until the sun rises, because this is what the Prophet (SAW) and his companions did, and because there is great reward in that.

> Muslim (670) narrated from Jaabir ibn Samurah that when the Prophet
>   (SAW) had prayed Fajr, he would
>   sit in his prayer place until the sun had risen properly.

And

> Muslim also narrated (670) that Sammaak ibn Harb said: I said to
>   Jaabir ibn Samurah: Did you sit with the Messenger of Allah (SAW)? He
>   said: Yes, frequently. He would not get up from the place in which he
>   had prayed Fajr until the sun had risen, and when the sun had risen he
>   would get up. They used to chat and talk about matters of the
>   Jaahiliyah, and they would laugh but he smiled.

Al-Tirmidhi narrated that

> Anas ibn Maalik (RA) said: The Messenger of Allah (SAW) said: “Whoever
>   prays Fajr in congregation then sits remembering Allah until the sun
>   rises, then prays two rak’ahs, will have a reward like that of Hajj
>   and ‘Umrah.” He said: The Messenger of Allah (SAW) said: “In full, in
>   full, in full.”

This hadeeth was classed as hasan by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Tirmidhi.

**Note:**

[Mustahabb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustahabb) actions are those whose status of approval in Islamic law falls between mubah (neither encouraged nor discouraged) and wajib (compulsory). **One definition is "duties recommended, but not essential; fulfilment of which is rewarded, though they may be neglected without punishment".** The opposite of mustahabb is makruh (discouraged).

Answer (score 0):

No it's only recommended ... and If you do you will be awarded a big prize (thawab) in the thereafter ... It's equivalent to thawab of a full hajj and Umrah ... also It have been the habit of good people since prophet Muhammed peace upon him

Comment: Could you support your claims by any evidence?